# Flutter android grey screen in release mode even if there are no errors or red screens in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, error-handling, release

I am getting grey screen on startup just after the splash screen on android real device. I have solved all errors or red screens and after that tried again but still it remains the same.

Note: I have released 2 versions of this app before this one to play store. So this is not the first one.

My log

```
Flutter run key commands.
h Repeat this help message.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
I/flutter (24661):                              <-- stops here nothing after this
```

Comment: a grey screen most probably indicates a UI error such as null pointer exception. Could you post the code for which screen its showing grey?

Comment: ok then its a ui error not a function error right?? As i have solved all function errors. Post the code...its showing at the start just after the splash screen i dont know for which page the problem has occurred.

Comment: Is the problem at the starting page or it can be anywhere in the app? i asked this because its showing at the start just after the splash screen?

Comment: @sameer kashyap I have editted the question...i hav added tht how app behaves in one of my phone in debug mode...it just gets stuck at installling... and tells signature diesnt matches in release mode but o another hone it shows grey screen in release mode and debug works fine.

Comment: Then it Most probably in one of the widgets that's shown early on, have you tried debug mode again? it should certainly show up.

Comment: is the data shown on the device consistent? Like if there's a empty field in your database for one of the user accounts, which is being accessed in the UI, it might cause.

Comment: No i tried the dubg mode and visited evry page of my app and there was no error or red screen. And about the null data then i have solved it already by giving initial values. When i ran in release mode i got grey screen again.

Comment: The log->   Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     692.3s (!)
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (51.7MB).
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                10.3s

Flutter run key commands.
h Repeat this help message.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
I/flutter (17690): <- stopped here

Comment: @sameerkashyap please invite others and your friends too...to help me please...so that it will be easy to track down the problem.

Comment: the grey screen only related to my code error or it can be plugin error and build error or some android error????

Comment: check your terminal for `Incorrect usage of Parent Widget`,the grey screen is a design issue it will work on debug mode,not release mode@Jagadish

Comment: in debug mode no error is shown in the terminal... but after that also can aa error still exist?

Comment: I had a similar issue. in my case, it was caused by not requesting device permissions correctly. check your permission code and only request permissions when it is not already granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing worked for me as there was no error in the UI. The error was at the beginning of the app in the main. After adding `await` before `Firebase.initializeApp();` worked like miracle.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  **await** Firebase.initializeApp(); //adding await solved the problem
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
    if (brightness == Brightness.dark) {
      prefs.setBool('darkMode', true);
    } else {}
    var darkModeOn = prefs.getBool('darkMode') ?? false;
    runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
        create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(darkModeOn ? darkTheme : lightTheme),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: root(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime it works well in debug mode but **not** **working** in release mode. You may catch that error by running below command in your terminal.

```
 flutter run --release
```

The command compiles to release mode. When grey screen happened, you can check your debug console.

Comment: I am doing that only...it's shoeing grey screen and in debug console nothing shows up...please read my question again.?.I need help...

Comment: `I/flutter (17690): <- stopped here`.   It seems like you have use `print` to print out something? Did you use the above command to run it as release mode?

Comment: No I haven't used print....the log stops there and yes I have used the command to run

Comment: @sameer kashyap , @aligator , and @Assassin please help the log reader stops at  `I/flutter (17690):` but it should show ` I/flutter (17690): completed or other things after that` i am afraid that its not a UI error maybe its some android build error or anything else please help me out....

Comment: but it should show ` I/flutter (17690): completed or other things after that`.. Why would you expect it will show this? Please post the relevant code

Comment: .....Because sometimes it woks automatically and then in the log it shoes all things like in debug mode but when it doesn't it gets stuck there. And more surprising is thats ten if there are no changes in code sometimes it works and sometimes it shoes grey screen.

Comment: the grey screen normally stuck at which page? do you use any `async-await` on that page?

Comment: The grey screen shoes just after thae splash screen...yes I use async and await on that page

Comment: Actually I use a root page which decides either she duser to login page or main page...I use shared preference to get that user has signed in or not and then return the page.

Comment: so the grey screen appear when first time sign in? Did you still get grey screen when open the app second time?

Comment: No it appears every time...when the app starts just after the splash screen but sometimes it does work on its own and the app works then after wards without any change also it doesn't work...should I make a repository of my code on GitHub ?

Comment: the grey screen just after indicates error at the beggining or the error can be anywhere in the app??

Comment: Ok sure let me create a private repository only for teams and include you in it...you can also add your friends you know who can help...and yes thanks a lot for helping me in advance!!!

Comment: does call `Firebase.initializeApp();` in main cause the problem or the grey screen can only be for UI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225139/discussion-between-jagadish-and-john-joe).